# How to prevent an AJAX callback on page exit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I make an AJAX call in a function on page exit:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
   on_close();
});
```

This works fine. But Firebug flashes an ugly red POST error. I have an empty my_method.js.erb file, because, of course, i have no use for a callback. I suspect the error is because AJAX is trying to force a callback, while the page is closing. So...is it possible to prevent AJAX, or the Rails controller, from even sending/expecting a callback?

Question extended - here's the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '/my_folder/my_method',                    
    dataType: "script",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}
});
```

Comment: What options do you use for AJAX-Request, extend you question(AJAX-Call, Firebug-Error-Log).

Comment: @Blauharley, thx. I can't inspect the Firebug error. It flashes, then the page refreshes. I'm looking into options, now...

Comment: Ok, I persisted the Firebug log. But there's nothing to show, no errors, just a clean ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

This removed the Firebug error flag - async: false,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/my_folder/my_method',                    
    dataType: "script",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}
});
```

Comment: I should have titled this - How to prevent an AJAX callback ERROR on page exit? Making the call synchronous allowed the callback (empty) to complete before page exit. Thus, no error. The callback, itself, did not need to be prevented.